# Getting facebook ads targeting country through api

Tags: location, facebook-marketing-api, targeting

I have a requirement where I want to extract the location targeting information for ads(country,region etc). Is it possible to get this information for each campaign?
   I read about the Facebook Marketing Insights API(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.9) but could not found any field related to this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The targeting information is set at Ad Set level. You can find out more about the camping structure here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api

So you need the retrieve the Ad set ID and then retrieve the Targeting for that Ad set:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign